# angular 4 group input fields from ngfor

Tags: angular

I have a ngFor to construct a table of 5 columns, containing 20 rows.
The first 2 columns are strings (name and points), the 3rd, 4th and 5th are input fields (lets say p1, p2 and p3 for now).
I can't figure out how to group these rows together when I submit my data. I tried giving the input fields a name combination of

`name="{{person.name}}-p1"`

but when I try to read data.value when I submit I end up with 60 properties, which is a pain to search through.

```
person1-p1: value
person1-p2: value
person1-p3: value
person2-p1: value
ect
```

Is there anyway to group them together, so that it looks something like this?

```
people: {
  person1: {p1: value, p2: value; p3: value},
  person2: {p1: value, p2: value; p3: value},
  person2: {p1: value, p2: value; p3: value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider the simplest way like ngForm?
In my opinion it is the best way to group that inputs.
Ofc you can create one form contating for example 5 forms.
https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Edit:

If you want to group inputs values in controller do sth like that:

```
interface Person {
p1: string;
p2: string;
}
array: Person[] = [{p1: '', p2: ''},{p1: '', p2: ''},{p1: '', p2: ''}];
```

and in html you can bind ngModel to all of values from array.

Comment: How do you mean? currently the whole table is in a ngForm. My form tag loops like this:
`<form class="col-md-12" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(personPointsForm)" #personPointsForm="ngForm">`
Inside this form I have the table, and inside the table body I loop through the list of people: `<tr *ngFor="let person of people" class="item">`

Comment: Do you want to have all values from inputs grouped in controller or sth else?

Comment: I need them grouped in my component.ts, so they need to be grouped in the onSubmit method

Comment: All right, so in my opinion the best way is to create array of objects (person) and use two way databinding.

Comment: I edited my answer, check it maybe it would help you.

Comment: working on it, will give it a try. I'll + you when I get it working, but I have a good feeling about this :) I'm a real newbie when it comes to angular :|

Comment: No problem, if you had any problem just write :)